# jQuery UI size effect on hover then return to original size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I'm still learning javascript, jQuery and jQuery UI and I'm trying to do something that seems so simple:

Make a gray div box expand to a larger size on hover and **remain** at the new size while hovering and *only* return to original size when you move your mouse away.

Here is my code:

```
$("div").hover(
 // Mouse Over: Expand to 75 x 75
  function(){
    $(this).effect("size", { to: {width: 75,height: 75} }, 1000);
  },
  // Mouse Out: 50 x 50 is original size
  function(){
    $(this).effect("size", { to: {width: 50,height: 50} }, 500);
});
```

I know I am close but it doesn't quite work right.  See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/L496W/1/ .  The box expands to the larger size but then shrinks back down while still hovering on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, would .toggle() help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

```
$("div").hover(
  // Mouse Over
  function(){
    $(this).animate({width: 75,height: 75}, 1000);
  },
  // Mouse Out
  function(){
      $(this).animate({width: 50,height: 50}, 1000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtc4y/)

Comment: It works!  Do you mind explaining why .animate() is preferable to .effect("size") here?

Comment: @ErikBerger jQuery UI's `.effect()` method is more of an emphasis animation than a permanent change of state animation. That is to say that it is used to call attention to things for a temporary amount of time. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/j7wQz/))